# How to avoid a task to do time consuming processing?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, software-design

I have an old embedded system model having linux threads - 1 process. Each thread or tasks speaks to each other by posting events. Once the event is posted, the thread reads the data from the sockbuffer. Sometime, this data may be too much. Thus, the task will be busy handling reading that sockbuffer. Also, there is one special task - that logs the entire user input history onto a RAM disk file. However, this comes into the action only one user clicks save button.

Condition - We don't have any control on the amount of data to be processed. This can be small or too large. Secondly, this is an embedded system, so we keep checking the health by checking whether the task is able to pat the watchdog or not.

Observation -

1. If the data is too much, then sock buffer read will take some time. Thus, it can cause other tasks to starve and hence it will cause a crash.
2. If the user history is too much, then writing the entire history(max) even on a ram-disk will consume time. Thus, all these will lead other tasks to starve i.e. not able to pat the wd. Thus, it will lead to a crash.

Problem - I can't redesign this software since it is ages old. Only, I can do some surgery or intelligent code to avoid these issues. What is the best way to fix these design issues?

-> I am using C, Linux.

Comment: What you mean by `linux threads - 1 process`? Are they POSIX threads mapped to single kernel thread associated with single user-space process? So, they are actually **user-level threads**, scheduled in user space only. In that case, any system call, performed by one of the threads, blocks all threads until it returns.

Comment: Rather than having your thread `read(ALOT)`, have it `while(!done) { read(A_LITTLE_BIT); sleep(0); }`?

Comment: Yes - don't understand how it's scheduled.  Normally, I would suggest lowering the priority of the logger thread, but with your design, I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: Also, this is SO.  We don't pat watchdogs here, we kick them:)

Comment: The usefulness of watchdogs in a mutithreaded system is itself somewhat dubious.  A hardware watchdog that is kicked by some idle thread every second is still fine for detecting total failures, but monitoring each thread in watchdog-manner is much less useful.